# max number of non overlapping substring

Tags: c++

Hi guys i am doing a question.The question is like:

"you are given a string “S” and a pattern “P”. You have to find FS (x, y) that is defined as the maximum number of non-overlapping substring which is equal to the pattern “P” in the substring

of S which starts at x and end at y (x ,y are in 0 base indexes ) .

Suppose,

S = “abcdef”

P = “cd”

and the query is (1,5) , so the substring will be “bcdef” and FS(1,5) = 1"

I am using an approach in which my code counts the number  of pattern P present between x and y but i am confused a bit because the problem statement says that count the "maximum" number of non overlapping substring.I think maximum here is written for confusion and has no significance because i cannot find any counter case.Please reply if i am thinking wrong.

In case you want the link to the problem:- [LINK](http://www.spoj.com/problems/TKUDDUS/)

or you want to see my code:-[CODE](http://ideone.com/ianWyC#view_edit_box)

```
//this is my code
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
#include "cstring"
#include "cstdlib"
#include "algorithm"
#include "cstdio"
using namespace std;

  #define gc getchar_unlocked

  void scanint(int &x)                      //fast input 
  {
    register int c = gc();
    x = 0;
    for(;(c<48 || c>57);c = gc());
    for(;c>47 && c<58;c = gc()) {x = (x<<1) + (x<<3) + c - 48;}
  }

  int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
  {
    int t,q,i,j,c=0,h,x;    string s;
    cin>>t;
    getline(cin,s);
    for(x=1;x<=t;x++)
    {cout<<"Case "<<x<<":"<<endl;
    string p,z;
    getline(cin,s);
    getline(cin,p);
    scanint(q);

    while(q--)
    {
        scanint(i);scanint(j);c=0;z.clear();
        for(h=i;h<=j;h++)
        {
            if(s[h]==p[0])
            {
                    if(p.length()==1)
                    z=s.substr(h,p.length());
                else if(p.length()<=(j-h)+1)
                    z=s.substr(h,p.length());
                    if(!z.compare(p))
                    {
                        c++;h=h+p.length()-1;
                    }

            }   
        }
        cout<<c<<endl;
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's with the `scanint` function?  Stream input can handle the conversion correctly (e.g. `std::istringstream` on the line you've read).  And `isdigit` is a lot more readable (and more portable) than comparing to magic constants.  None of the headers you include declare `getchar_unlocked` (at least on a conformant implementation), and the function doesn't exist on most platforms.  (On the one platform where I seem to remember it, `Solaris`, it interacted with stream input in strange ways as well, and shouldn't be used on a stream where there is stream input.)

Comment: You should fix the indentation as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regex` for this purpose, just construct `sregex_iterator` (you have to give it a regex pattern and a string subrange in which you want to search for occurences of this pattern) and iterate over it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int substr_occurences(string str, int start_idx, int end_idx, string pattern)
{
    const regex reg("(" + pattern + ")");
    int occurences = 0;

    sregex_iterator it(str.begin() + start_idx, str.begin() + 1 + end_idx, reg);
    sregex_iterator it_end;

    while(it != it_end)
    {
        ++occurences;
        cout << (*it)[1] << endl;
        it++;
    }

    return occurences;
}
```

If you are new to regex in C++ have a look at [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-8-of-n).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the range which interests you with `begin() + x` and `begin() + y` on the string.  After that, just iterate for as long as `std::search` returns something other than the end iterator, counting.

Comment: i am confused about the "maximum" thing does that have any significance?